# window.scrollTo and behavior not working on IOS

Tags: javascript

Before I start, I'm sorry for using a translator to write. :(

I knew that the behavior attribute was not only available in Safari in IOS.

So I tested it with Iphone 13 pro, but it not working in safari and chrome.

What do I know wrong?

```
<body style="height: 5000px;">
  <button onclick="test()">click</button>
  <script>
    function test(){
      window.scrollTo({top:2000, behavior:"smooth"})
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `Window.scrollTo` will only work on [iOS 14 and above](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo#browser_compatibility). To make this work on iOS 13 and below, use a [polyfill](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll).